# How to get random value from a file in python?

Tags: file, python-2.7, key-value, random

It would have been very gratifying to figure this out by myself but I haven't been able to.

I want to grab a random value from a text file that contains data in the form of a dictionary eg:

```
{'One': '1111111', 'Two': '2222222', 'Three': '3333333'}
```

I've tried a few variations, but code is currently:

```
from random import *

table = open('file.txt')
random_value = random.choice(table.values())
```

When I try and print 'random_value' (to see if it is working), I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Answer (score 1):

`table` is a file object, and thus you want to turn it into a dictionary. Here I use the [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html) module:

```
from random import choice # No need to import everything if you're going to use just one function
import ast
table = open('file.txt').read()
mydict = ast.literal_eval(table)
random_value = choice(mydict.values())
```

Comment: thank you very much, i am getting 'malformed string' error when trying to print random_value.

Comment: `table` is still a file object... And you need to change `random.choice` to just `choice`

Comment: @user1063287 That would mean in file.txt, the dictionary is not proper syntax. Also, I edited my question because I accidentally changed something to make it incorrect. Try now

Comment: Okay everything should be fine. @user1063287 Don't forget to open the file in read mode, like I just did :p :)

Comment: thank you very much, it is returning a random value, but it seems to be 'locked' to one random value and just prints the same value repeatedly, eg in the following example:

for _ in range(10):
    print random_value

Comment: @user1063287 Well yea, because we only called the function once for one variable. What were you expecting :O? (I'll try add it to my answer :))